# Sub report is not fetching information in notification

Tags: acumatica

I have added functionality to accept multiple e Signature for a shipment module and the pick list report is modified to print those signatures.

I have added a sub report to print those signature(s)

[image]

The Report works fine from the report section, but it fails to fetch the signature information if the report is attached to notification. The signature page comes as blank.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have revisited the parameter and passed the shipment number for the record set instead of parameter variable.

Thanks to Gabriel

[image]

I have changed the parameter value to

[image]